# How to use last_insert_id() with "ADODB.Connection" object correctly?

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, adodb

I'm having a problem in retrieving last record id from database. This code below, is the closer I can get. But still, it return record id, as 0; ,then when I execute again, it will return, record of previous execute, not the current one.

```
sql = "insert into program (prog_det,budget,prog_obj,outcome,target_group,awareness,engagement,issue,seq_no) value ('"&prog_title&"','"&prog_budget&"','"&prog_obj&"','"&prog_result&"','"&prog_target&"','"&prog_aware&"','"&prog_involment&"','"&prog_issues&"','99');"

sql2 = "select last_insert_id() as last_id"

set kpi_prog_conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set kpi_prog_rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

kpi_prog_conn.Open ObjConn
kpi_prog_conn.Execute(sql)

kpi_prog_conn.Open sql2,objConn,adLockPessimistic

response.write kpi_prog_rs("last_id")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your penultimate line looks wrong

Try

```
kpi_prog_rs.Open sql2,kpi_prog_conn,adLockPessimistic
```

Answer (score 0):

IS the ID you are trying to retrieve is the Primary key of the corresponding table? Try using Scope_Identity() instead of last_insert_id()

Query - SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [LAST_IDENTITY]

It returns you the last inserted id into the table

Comment: could u pls show some example , of how i should write it the way u mention above?

Comment: U are right in saying scope_identity is not for mysql. it was my wrong assumption that you are using sql server. I am trying to figure out another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have mysql but try:

```
sql2 = "select last_insert_id() as last_id;"
sql = "insert into program (prog_det,budget,prog_obj,outcome,target_group,awareness,engagement,issue,seq_no) value ('"&prog_title&"','"&prog_budget&"','"&prog_obj&"','"&prog_result&"','"&prog_target&"','"&prog_aware&"','"&prog_involment&"','"&prog_issues&"','99');" & sql2
set kpi_prog_conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
kpi_prog_conn.Open ObjConn
set kpi_prog_rs = kpi_prog_conn.Execute(sql)
anotherRecordset = kpi_prog_rs.NextRecordset
response.write anotherRecordset("last_id")
```